# Search View For Admin In magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

I have created a Sample Module (Admin Side) in Magento.. I managed To created a form and Then Stored the form field values in Database. Now I am trying To create a search view for that. to show me all the values which i have stored in my table. however i am not able to get it. when i press the tab I directly get the form view. I want the search view first and a button there which ll direct me to this form. I want it the same way as it is for product, category or any other module. Do anyone Know How can I do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a grid. The process is kind of long to explain here, but if you search online there are a few tutorials that explain how to do it (here's one that I found useful: http://www.webspeaks.in/2010/08/create-admin-backend-module-in-magento.html). Keep in mind that you can also model your own code after core code. If you want to make a grid like the Category grid, then go look in the code how its made.